# Why require open supersets in definition of Lebesgue measurability

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-measure

In the definition of Lebesgue measurability, I require for $E$ to be measurable that for any $\epsilon$, there is an open superset $A \supset E$ such that $m^*(A \setminus E) \leq \epsilon$.

Why require that $A$ is open? What would break otherwise?

Comment: If $A$ could be any old set, you could just take $A=E$.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But why open? Why not (for example) closed? Or anything else that would constraint the set in a reasonable way, really...

Comment: Closed sets wouldn't work. If $E$ is the set of all rational numbers, then the only closed set containing $E$ is the whole line. Measurable sets would work, but not much use for defining measurability. Borel sets (or $G_\delta$-sets) would work, and you could say $m^*(A\setminus E)=0$ instead of $\le\epsilon$. But I guess the idea was to find the simplest definition of measurability that would work, not the most complicated one.